# Google Colab RAM keeps on being used up

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

So I am working on making a neural network, and since I have a laptop with integrated graphics I figured it would be better to use Google Colab's cloud resources.

However, when I run my notebook's cells, the kernel keeps on crashing for simple functions. For example, I am working with an array of shape (37000, 180, 180, 1) but when I run np.array() on said array the session crashes, saying that the RAM has been overflooded. It also crashes when I attempt to save anything.

It also doesn't give the option to switch to a high RAM runtime, but only gives the option to view any logs. Is there a reason that Colab keeps on crashing, and how can I fix this?